# How to restart Service using IntentService in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am able to stop my ServiceA(it is started using `AlarmManager`) when an `IntentService` is running by sending a broadcast from `IntentService` to broadcast receiver. I want to Start the same ServiceA again after my `IntentService` finished his work.

Ex-I have Service `SrvA`,IntentService `IntSrvB` and BroadcastReceiver `MyBcr`.When my `IntSrvB` running i am able to stop `SrvA`.My problem is How to Restart `SrvA` again when my `IntSrvB` finish his work.

Note-`ServA` is started using `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Let i have a Service ServiceA which is running(it is started using AlarmManager).At the same time i want to send the location data for this i use IntentService which need WiFi Enable.But My Service i.e ServiceA having method which Disables WIFI.That`s why i want to stop that service and I am able to do this.my question is how to restart ServiceA when my IntentService finish his work.

Comment: try to override `onDestroy()` method of your `IntentService`. And start `ServiceA` via Intent from there (i mean call `startService(serviceIntent)`).  You can create `serviceIntent` with flags which will not run your `ServiceA` if it's allready running.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan if you get what i want to do suggest me.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan ServiceA is started using AlarmManager.so to stop that we need to write pendingIntent.cancel() and stop service method. if we start the same ServiceA using startService(serviceIntent) ,it will get a null pointer as the pending intent is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on your code, you can pass your variables `myIntent` & `myIntent2` into your `IntentService` class - you can then use them to recreate exact replicas of the pending intents used with the `AlarmManager`.

Please note that it looks like you set an Alarm for each intent that repeats once "NOW" and then at intervals after that. You then implicitly start the service again i.e. you start the service twice "NOW". That looks like a mistake - look at the docs for the [AlarmManager.setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method.

---

Original answer below...

Put this into your `IntentService`:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        // STOP SERVICE

        // DO YOUR WORK HERE
    }
    finally
    {
        // START SERVICE
    }

}
```

You already have the code to stop the service. You can take the "start service" code from your  `BroadcastReceiver` and put it in the finally block.

I would not recommend overriding `onDestroy()` in general on Android.

**NOTE**: I don't think this is the best way to design your app, but I'm answering your question. Personally, I would have a method in my main `Service` that is able to disable & enable its functionality - and then call that method instead of starting & stopping the service.

Comment: as i mentioned SrvA is Started using AlarmManager to stop that i need to do `pendingintent.cancel(). When i want to restart the same service SrvA ,i will get a null pointer.

Comment: @thesimple Pls add code - you are not clear. Maybe you are asking about cancelling an alarm, not stopping a `Service`. If you are getting null pointers, then check for null. -Please add code-