# How to Restart Android IntentService

Tags: android, exception, service

I have an intent service which is processing long running task. But while processing if an exception occurs lets say SocketTimeOutException the service stops. How to catch the exception and restart the process.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String packageName = intent.getStringExtra("packageName");
        String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
        int downloadedSoFar = 0;

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadListViewApp.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText("Download in progress")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setContentInfo("0%").setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);

        try {
            url = new URL(IPClass.SERVERIP + path + "/" + packageName);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(7000);
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            connection.connect();

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Android/appdata/tmp/downloadtmp/" + packageName, true);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            boolean continueLoop = true;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) > 0 && continueLoop) {
                    progressChange((int) (downloadedSoFar * 100L) / fileLength, packageName);
                    downloadedSoFar = downloadedSoFar + count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) output.close();
                if (input != null) input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776012/2705391
You can use this for your problem.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        // STOP SERVICE

        // DO YOUR WORK HERE
    }
    finally
    {
        // START SERVICE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop intent service till its duty has completed, if you want to stop it then you should have to stop alarm manager in intent service like this.

```
    Intent DataSyncing = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DataSyncingScheduledReceiver.class);
    DataSyncing.setAction(DataSyncingScheduledReceiver.ACTION_DATASYNC_RECEIVER);
    PendingIntent DataSyncingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),1003, DataSyncing, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManagerdatasync = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManagerdatasync.cancel(DataSyncingIntent);
    DataSyncingIntent.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think restarting a servise is not a solution you should handle it in catch

put your code to call api inside seperate function 
supose your function is like callAPI()

```
} catch (final java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // connection timed out...let's try again   
    callAPI()   
}
```

This creates a recursion
by this your api will be called n time untill your api will give SocketTimeoutException
so you will not need to restart your IntentService. it will remain onrun until your api executed

if you want to prevent this you have to specify and implement logic of nuberofAttempts  as in volley
volley inbuilt has retry policy you should read about it.
else i sugest volley or retrofit to use

Comment: But I want a button click first before doing anything else. So its Activity -> Service event (bus event not working) any idea ?